# Rounding LinearExpr with google or-tools SAT solver

Tags: java, nonlinear-optimization, or-tools, sat

I'm creating a constraint (in Java) using [or-tools SAT solver](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver):

```
IntVar x, y, z;
IntVar[] variables = new IntVar{x, y, z};
int[] multiplier = new int{2, 3, 3};
LinearExpr expression = LinearExpr.scalProd(variables, multiplier); //2x + 3y + 3z
model.addLessThan(expression, q);
```

Where `q` is some given integer.

The thing is that I need to round the expression result.
Something like:

```
if(expression < 25) {
    expression = 0;
} else if(expression < 75) {
    expression = 50;
} else if(expression < 125) {
    expression = 100;
} else if(expression < 175) {
    expression = 150;
} else if(expression < 225) {
    expression = 200;
} else if(expression < 275) {
    expression = 250;
} else {
    expression = 300;
}
```

---

So that the value of the `expression` (which should be used in the `addLessThan` constraint) is one of the following:

```
0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300
```

---

Let's review 2 cases:

**Case 1**

`q = 180` and `expression = 176`.

Although the condition `176 < 180` is `true`, after rounding up 176 to 200 the tested condition should be `200 < 180` which is `false`.

So for `q = 180` and `expression = 176` I would like the condition to return `false`.

---

**Case 2**

`q = 210` and `expression = 218`.

Although the condition `218 < 210` is `false`, after rounding down 218 to 200 the tested condition should be `200 < 210` which is `true`.

So for `q = 210` and `expression = 218` I would like the condition to return `true`.

---

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I guess you could create a boolean for each case, create another intvar and set that value based on that, there should be a better way though

Comment: @Stradivari I just updated the question with 2 examples. I'm not sure I'm getting you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment (code in Python):

```py
roundedExpr = model.NewIntVarFromDomain(cp_model.Domain.FromValues([0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300]), "roundedExpr")

b1 = model.NewBoolVar("< 25")
model.Add(expression < 25).OnlyEnforceIf(b1)
model.Add(roundedExpr == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(b1)
...
b7 = model.NewBoolVar(">= 275")
model.Add(expression >= 275).OnlyEnforceIf(b7)
model.Add(roundedExpr == 300).OnlyEnforceIf(b7)

model.AddBoolOr([b1, b2, b3, ..., b7])
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I was able to implement it. Do you happen to know how can I implement such a solution if the expression is non-linear?  I asked it in a separated question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62804600/rounding-non-linearexpr-with-google-or-tools-sat-solver