# Rounding Non-LinearExpr with google or-tools SAT solver

Tags: optimization, or-tools, nonlinear-optimization, cp-sat

Using [CP-SAT of google or-tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/sat/sat_solver/SatSolver) I'm trying to write this constraint:

```
q >= (50x + 100y + 150z + 200k + 250p + 300v) / (x + y + z + k + p + v)
```

Where `q` is a simple integer.

The thing is I need to round the right side of the equation (let's call it `expression`) as follows:

```
if(expression < 75) {
    expression = 50;
} else if(expression < 125) {
    expression = 100;
} else if(expression < 175) {
    expression = 150;
} else if(expression < 225) {
    expression = 200;
} else if(expression < 275) {
    expression = 250;
} else {
    expression = 300;
}
```

So I need to round the expression

`(50x + 100y + 150z + 200k + 250p + 300v) / (x + y + z + k + p + v)`

So that it gets one of the following values:

```
{50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300}
```

---

Let's review 2 cases:

**Case 1**

`q = 180` and `expression = 176`.

Although the condition `180 >= 176` is `true`, after rounding up 176 to 200 the tested condition should be `180 >= 200` which is `false`.

So for `q = 180` and `expression = 176` I would like the condition to return `false`.

---

**Case 2**

`q = 210` and `expression = 218`.

Although the condition `210 >= 218` is `false`, after rounding down 218 to 200 the tested condition should be `210 >= 200` which is `true`.

So for `q = 210` and `expression = 218` I would like the condition to return `true`.

---

I got a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646674/rounding-linearexpr-with-google-or-tools-sat-solver) for resolving this challenge over a linear expression but now I need to resolve it for a non-linear expression.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are the variables positive ?

Comment: @LaurentPerron Yes, the variables positive

Comment: So expression always <= 15

Comment: @LaurentPerron I've changed the data a bit, now it's the full expression I'm dealing with. I wrote a shorter version before to try and keep it simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's rephrase

you have an integer variable `e` with a value between 0 and 300.
You want to round it to the nearest multiple of 50

if you do:

```
(e div 50) * 50
```

you will get the max multiple of 50 less or equal to `e`

```
(70 / 50) * 50 -> 50
(99 / 50) * 50 -> 50
(102 / 50) * 50 -> 100
```

To get a round to nearest, you need to add 25 to `e` before the division

```
((e + 25) div 50) * 50
```

Which will do the correct rounding

```
((70 + 25) / 50) * 50 -> 50
((99 + 25) / 50) * 50 -> 100
((102 + 25) / 50) * 50 -> 100
```

with the correct or-tools CP-SAT python code:

```
numerator = model.NewIntVar(...)
model.Add(numerator == 50x + 100y + 150z + 200k + 250p + 300v)
denom = model.NewIntVar(...)
model.Add(denom == 50x + 100y + 150z + 200k + 250p + 300v)
e = model.NewIntVar(0, 300, 'e')
model.AddDivisionEquality(e, numerator, denom)

shifted_e = model.NewIntVar(25, 325, 'shifted_e')
model.Add(shifted_e == e + 25)
multiple_of_fifty = model.NewIntVar(0, 6, 'multiple_of_fifty')
model.AddDivisionEquality(multiple_of_fifty, shifted_e, 50)
result = model.NewIntVar(0, 300, 'result')
model.Add(result = multiple_of_fifty * 50)
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand now the idea of adding 25 to e before the division. In your CP-SAT solution e stands for the expression I need to round (right?), I'm having trouble defining the expression itself since it's a non-linear expression.

Comment: I have added the code to define e. I believe you can use only one division. I need to write it down.

Answer (score 1):

if a and b are positive then

```
a div b >= q
```

is equivalent to

```
a >= q * b
```

now, your example does not specify how to round (nearest or down)

if you want to round down

```
q * (x + y + z + k + p + v) <= (50x + 100y + 150z + 200k + 250p + 300v)
```

If you want to round to nearest, you need to add q / 2 in the right place

```
 q * (x + y + z + k + p + v) <= (50x + 100y + 150z + 200k + 250p + 300v + q / 2)
```

Now, if you want the other direction

```
a div b <= q
```

is equivalent to

```
a <= q * b + q - 1
```

The rest of the transformation is the same.

Comment: I need to round down the expression (50x + 100y + 150z + 200k + 250p + 300v) / (x + y + z + k + p + v).  I agree that a div b >= q is equivalent to a >= q * b, but considering my rounding constraint I can't how it helps me. Can you explain?

Comment: The first line is : I want to write this constraint q <= (50x + 100y + 150z + 200k + 250p + 300v) / (x + y + z + k + p + v). This is exactly what I did.

Comment: Anyway, a = 50x + 100y + 150z + 200k + 250p + 300v, b = 50 * (x + y + z + k + p + v) + 25. c = a / b. what you want is c * 50

Comment: Please notice that my question refers to how to write this constraint using CP-SAT of google or-tools. Second, I'm sorry but I don't understand the math, why did you multiplied the denominator by 50 and added 25?

Comment: I've changed the sign direction, q >= expression.  Your suggestion is to add q/2 to the expression? Look at the second example in my question (case 2), I believe your suggestion does not resolve it.

Comment: I have added the other direction for the inequation in my answer.